# change ubercart order success message Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

In Drupal 7, I am using Ubercart.

After placing an order it shows a message like this:

> Your order is complete! Your order number is...

I want to change this message.

I tried to change `function uc_cart_uc_message()`, but it is not changing.

Comment: Anyone have any idea, how can i do .. Thank you

Comment: No anyone know about it ??

Comment: Guys i solved it by my self